# Remove Empty from word document using Open XMl in >net Core

Tags: .net-core, ms-word, openxml-sdk

Removing the empty line from the word document the using Open Xml in .Net core

Comment: To improve the question put the code you have tried so that we can help you better. Do you have to delete a specific empty line or e.g. the last empty line of the document?

Comment: For Example in word document I have

To: ClientName
      ClientAddress1
      ClientAddress2

If ClientName is not available it comes up with Empty line

foreach (Text element in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>())
    {
        if (element.Text == "ClientName")
            element.Remove();
    }

I have used this piece of code but it didn't work

Comment: your code works for me, to clarify a little more when you delete the text there is an empty line you also have to delete it?

Comment: Yes need to delete the empty line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the line you also have to delete the paragraph, this is due to the structure of word:

```
<w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>ClientName</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

First there is the paragraph and inside there is the text, if there is no text it is a blank paragraph.

What you were doing was deleting the text, but you also had to remove the paragraph.

Try the following to see if it helps.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("WordPath", true))
{
    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
    {
         Text text = paragraph.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
         if (text != null)
         {
             if (text.Text.Equals("ClientName"))
             {
                 paragraph.Remove();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)